# Buggy EvaluationUnmatchedStyle for backgrounds with opacity

Tags: cells, style, customization, background

The `EvaluationUnmatchedStyle` option of [PrivateCellOptions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PrivateCellOptions.html) was introduced in v10, wherein any time input is changed, the corresponding output dims to signify that output is no longer consistent with input. An old thread on this topic: [Faded output is printed from dynamic object](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/70226/faded-output-is-printed-from-dynamic-object)

While playing around with cell background colors, I found that if some really output cell background color with certain opacity is chosen, the dimming breaks.

**Consistent Input and Output :**

[image: when input and outputs match]

**Inconsistent Input and Output :**

[image: when input and output don't match]

Is there any way to control the dimming level manually? Is there any value one can pass to `EvaluationUnmatchedStyle` that is not the buggy `EvaluationUnmatched`?

You can reproduce this behavior with this example setting: `Background->RGBColor[ 0.388235,0.933333,0.388235, 0.1]`

**Possible implementation of `EvaluationUnmatchedStyle` :**

I think I understand how the `EvaluationUnmatched` value of `EvaluationUnmatchedStyle` is being implemented.

```
myEvaluationUnmatched = {PrivateCellOptions -> {"ContentsOpacity" ->.5}}
CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, {PrivateCellOptions,"EvaluationUnmatchedStyle"}] = myEvaluationUnmatched
```

To my eyes the effect of this identical to the default one

```
CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, {PrivateCellOptions,"EvaluationUnmatchedStyle"}] = "EvaluationUnmatched"
```

This means the real issue is with the implementation of `ContentsOpacity`.

**Addendum:**

The issue is `ContentsOpacity` doesn't play nice with RGB color that comes with it's own opacity i.e. `RGBColor[r,g,b,a].` My background color had some opacity of its own, and dropping that makes everything work fine.

However, I would still be curious to know if `ContentsOpacity` can be made to work on background colors with predefined opacity.